# How to customised ListView that have repeated structure in Android?

Tags: android, listview, subitem

I'm new to android and I want to customize my application that have structures like following:

```
CompanyName-1:abc
  employee-1:
  employee-2:

CompanyName-2:pqr
  employee-1:


CompanyName-3:xyz
  employee-1:
  employee-2:
  employee-3:
  employee-4:
```

In above structures, employee size may vary depending on data you have i.e. if your company have only 1 employee it should display only one employee, if 2 then 2 employees and etc.

Comment: use expandable listview for http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html such type of stucture

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make a good java structure with your data, for example a "company object" that contain an "ArrayList of employee". Afterwards, be interested with getView() method from your adapter.(Adapter for your listView).

Good Luck!